# Split jQuery selection

Tags: jquery

i got following line

```
$('#formSelect option[value="'+ json.name + '"]').remove();
```

This deletes an option inside a form. Which option depends on `json.name`.

So do you know an alternative way to do this?
Maybe something in the form like this:

```
var rmOption = ???
$('#formSelect rmOption').remove();
```

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative ? I don't see what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Do you mean `var rmOption = 'option[value="'+ json.name + '"]'; $('#formSelect ' + rmOption).remove();`

Comment: Sounds strange. If you need to delete `option` which depends on `json.name` of course there are couple more variants of how to find this `option`... however, they all still will depend on `json.name`.

Comment: @Vega Yes, i meant something like this, thanks, maybe know a nice way to integrate json.name...

Comment: @dystroy ok, i keep it like this, i thought there is a smarter way to this without all these quotes.

Comment: You might remove some of the quotes but that would be less safe and no cleaner.

Comment: @jubi4dition Believe, your way is normal, and there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @jubi4dition Try using filter if you don't like those quotes :) See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you mean var rmOption = 'option[value="'+ json.name + '"]'; $('#formSelect ' + rmOption).remove();
>
> @Vega Yes, i meant something like this, thanks, maybe know a nice way to integrate json.name...

You can try setting the options var and append it inside the selector like below,

```
var rmOption = 'option[value="'+ json.name + '"]';
$('#formSelect ' + rmOption).remove();
```

Or you can do the iterate that jQuery would be doing internally,

```
$('#formSelect option').filter(function () {
    return (this.value == json.name)
}).remove();
```

Comment: @VisioN Thanks, I was googling "retirm", expecting some magical function...

Comment: @Vision Thanks.. that was some awesome typo..

Comment: just a slight translation of your right hand fingers to the right, if you have a qwerty keyboard.

Comment: @dystroy Sorry, I broke your inspiration... :(

Comment: You know, filtering makes more sense than using attribute selector. +1 from me.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know, thanks, now i will think about it, if i use it.

Answer (score -1):

In your application, is it feasible to give each option a unique ID? That way you would just use the same .remove() tag and select that particular id.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
$('#formSelect ' + rmOption).remove();
```